# send_media_group aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Изначально пользователь отправляет две фотографии которые успешно записываются в список media. Почему при выполнении функции start_ex бот сначала присылает первое фото, а только потом медиа группу из двух фото?

```
media = []  


def media_func(message: types.Message):
    global media  
    if message.media_group_id:
        print('ok')
        photo_data = message.photo
        p_id = photo_data[0].file_id
        print(p_id)
        media.append(p_id)
        print(media)
    return media


async def start_ex(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, userstate, problem):
    global media
    f_id = media_func(message)
    media_group = MediaGroupBuilder()
    for i in f_id:
        print(i)
        media_group.add_photo(i)
        print(media_group)
    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=message.chat.id, media=media_group.build())
```